# WPF Programming Examples (Photo widget)

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

Anyone know (or can provide) a programming/XAML example with WPF of a image collection widget similar in principle to that of Picasa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Picasa, but had to tackle an image collection myself lately. http://photosuru.com/ was the best I could find.